# CollapsingToolbarLayout gets stuck sometimes with SwipeRefreshLayout beneath

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I am experiencing an issue with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` being left in a half-open state when I scroll quickly (up or down) the content beneath the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

In other words, when I swipe very quickly on the RecyclerView (up or down), the CollapsingToolbar gets stuck or jams up with the CollapsingToolbar in a half open state.

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` beneath it. The `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` holds a `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. The collapsingToolbarLayout is programmatically added.

RecyclerView within SwipeRefreshLayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Some of the CollapsingToolbarLayout Params

```
final AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
```

I am wondering if anyone is experiencing this issue and knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in the support library v26 version